# Comparing an int against multiple int arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

Let's say I have an integer called mapId and a collection of three int arrays composed of map numbers. Depending on the map the user is on, an item would be spawned. For this example, we can refer to three items as: `common_item`, `uncommon_item`, and `rare_item`.

```
int mapId;

int[] easyMaps = { 7, 10, 3, 44 };
int[] mediumMaps = { 17, 14, 32, 11, 79, 80, 82, 90, 111 };
int[] hardMaps = { 92, 98, 112, 145 };
```

What I'm looking to do is something such as:
if the player is on an easy map, spawn: `common_item`
if the player is on a medium difficulty map, spawn: `uncommon_item` and `common_item`
if the player is on a hard map, spawn: `rare_item`, `uncommon_item`, and `common_item`

How could I accomplish this without writing three separate for loops and looping through the three arrays separately? Is there a better way of accomplishing this concept of hierarchy without the heavy use of arrays and loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, another option which I like is in the `System.Linq` namespace, [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You could then write:

```
if(easyMaps.Contains(mapId)) {
    //stuff
}
```

I prefer the readability of that, personally.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to iterate through these each array manually.  you can use the `Array.IndexOf<int>(array, value)`.  This function will return the `index` of the value in the given array, or `-1` if it is not in the array.  You can just use if statements similar to this:

```
if(Array.IndexOf<int>(easyMaps, mapId) != -1){
     //Spawn common_item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[Array.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** method here like below:

```
if(Array.Exists(easyMaps, mapId)) {     // common_items
    // your logic
}

if(Array.Exists(mediumMaps, mapId)) {   // uncommon_items
    // your logic
}

if(Array.Exists(hardMaps, mapId)) {     // rare_items
    // your logic
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:
Given a mapId, get the difficulty level and then decide what to spawn.

**Solution:**
Use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep link from mapId to Level, with the added benefit that the lookup in dictionary is going to be faster than searching the array.

Here's the code:

```
namespace StackOverflow27884119
{
    public enum Level
    {
        Easy,
        Medium,
        Hard
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static Dictionary<int, Level> mapsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Level>()
                {
                    {7, Level.Easy}, {10, Level.Easy}, {3, Level.Easy}, {44, Level.Easy},
                    {17, Level.Medium}, {14, Level.Medium}, /*...*/ {111, Level.Medium},
                    {92, Level.Hard}, {98, Level.Hard}, {112, Level.Hard}, {145, Level.Hard},
                };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mapId = 3;
            SpawnItem(3);
        }

        private static void SpawnItem(int mapId)
        {
            Level level;
            bool found = mapsDictionary.TryGetValue(mapId, out level);
            if (found)
            {
                switch (level)
                {
                    case Level.Easy:
                        // spawn common_item
                        break;
                    case Level.Medium:
                        // spawn common_item
                        // spawn uncommon_item
                        break;
                    case Level.Hard:
                        // spawn common_item
                        // spawn uncommon_item
                        // spawn rare_item
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:** I didn't exactly understand what exactly spawning an item means. If it's some kind of behaviour, you can think about using strategy pattern instead of the switch case.